# Presenting a view controller triggers UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I've got a universal app that supports both iPad and iPhone, and on the iPhone it supports `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown`.

When I run the app on an iPhone, then rotate the device to `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown`, then modally present a view controller like this:

```
UIViewController* vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController* navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                              initWithRootViewController:vc];
navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Very unexpectedly, this triggers `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification`.

OK, so maybe this is because the modal view controller does not support the upside-down portrait orientation. Let's make a custom subclass of `UIViewController` that overrides `supportedInterfaceOrientations`:

```
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

But no difference, presenting the custom VC still triggers the notification. I also noticed that the notifications is **not** triggered on iPad, only on iPhone. Finally, the behaviour is the same in iOS 8 and iOS 7 (specifically I am testing on iOS 8.1 and iOS 7.1, but I doubt that this makes any difference).

Question: Is it normal that this notification is sent when a modal VC is presented? Why does it happen only for `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown`, but not for the regular portrait or any of the two landscape orientations? And why does it happen only on iPhone, not on iPad?

Note: I can provide a more complete, minimal running example on request.

Comment: Check "Deployment Info" and see whether your app supports UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown. If not, enable it, and see whether you still see the same.

Comment: @JoeSmith Yes, the app supports that orientation. In fact, being a universal app, it supports all 4 possible orientations. In `Info.plist` there is only one key `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations`, not device-specific keys with `~iphone` and `~ipad` tacked on. The reason is that the app also has a landscape UI on iPhone 6+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, indeed, that the modally presented view controller did not support `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown`. My idea to add an override of `supportedInterfaceOrientations` was correct, but where I went wrong was that I added the override to the custom subclass of `UIViewController` - *but this is **not** the presented view controller!*

The presented view controller, as my code snippet shows, is the `UINavigationController` instance. One correct solution to my problem therefore is to create a subclass of `UINavigationController` and add `supportedInterfaceOrientations` to that subclass.

---

Another correct, but in my case more elegant solution than subclassing is to make use of the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol.

Step 1: Modify the code snippet from my question:

```
UIViewController* vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController* navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                              initWithRootViewController:vc];
navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
// --- THE NEXT LINE IS NEW ---
navigationController.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Step 2: Make sure that the class that contains the presenting code (= the above code snippet) adopts the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol.

Step 3 (yes, there *is* a step 3): Add this protocol method to the newly designated delegate class:

```
- (NSUInteger) navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations:(UINavigationController*)navigationController
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

If you have many places where you present view controllers you will probably want to have some shared object that adopts `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, but that's part of your application design.